# The Sql Database is not deleted

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I'm getting an error deleting a database I created about a year ago. in the error, when I run these codes, it says:

```
USE MASTER;  
GO  
DROP DATABASE StoreDatabase;  
GO
```

**Cannot drop the database 'StoreDatabase', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

when I try to manually delete it manually

Right-click => Delete => Delete Backup and restore history information for database and Close Existing connections

in the error message it says:

**The object of type "Database" named "StoreDatabase" does not exist on the server (SqlManagerUI)**

how can I solve this error. thank you for your help.

Comment: Is it called `StoredDatabase` or `StoreDatabase`? What software are you using to do this: if C# you can't use `GO`, or are you actually using SSMS? Do you have permissions to drop the database? And if you want to delete the whole database why would you select `Delete Backup and restore history information`

Comment: Yes, I Edited by StoreDatabase, and i selected Delete Backup and restore history information.  But it didn't work

Comment: Is it shown in `sys.databases`?

Comment: Yes but you've not answered any of my other questions. What software? What permissions do you have? What are you actually trying to do: 1. drop the database or 2. delete backup history?

Comment: In the .NET Framework 5.0 in C#. I tried to create a migration in a Web API project.  I don't know exactly where to look at this with what permissions.

Answer (score 2):

> The Sql Database is not deleted

You do not delete a database but DROP it

> Cannot drop the database 'StoreDatabase', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Error includes two parts: (1) database does not exist or (2) you do not have permission. Please connect the server using SSMS or Azure Data Studio

(1) Use SSMS and execute the following query in order to confirm that the database exists

```
select DatabaseName = [name] FROM sys.databases
where [name] = 'StoreDatabase'
GO
```

(2) In order to DROP a database you need to have `CONTROL` permission on the database, or `ALTER ANY DATABASE` permission on the server, or to be membership in the `db_owner` fixed database role. Execute the following query to check that you have the permissions

```
USE StoreDatabase;  
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions (NULL, 'DATABASE')
where permission_name = 'CONTROL'
GO

SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'SERVER')
where permission_name = 'ALTER ANY DATABASE'
GO

USE master;
select DatabaseName = [name], DatabaseOwner = suser_sname(owner_sid) 
FROM sys.databases
where [name] = 'StoreDatabase'
GO
```

Try to DROP the database when you are connected as sysadmin (for example the USER `sa`)